# UWP - How do I center a button?

Tags: c#, uwp, winui, winui-3

I created a UWP solution and created a button. There are no problems with the buttons.

**I do not know how to center the button in the window.**

---

**Code**

```
        StackPanel stackPanel1 = new StackPanel();

        Button TestButton = new Button();
        TestButton.Content = "Test";

        stackPanel1.Children.Add(subscribeButton);
  
        Window.Current.Content = stackPanel1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is all you need.

```
TestButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the position of the button to half of the form's width and height will work.

```
Point point = new Point(this.Width / 2 - (button1.Width/2), this.Height / 2 - (button1.Height/ 2)); 
button1.Location = point;
```

The added `- (button1.Width/2)` is because the button's position is based on the upper right hand corner of the button, and not actually the center.

Comment: The method `.Location` doesn't exist.

Comment: Does `.Translation` work? It's a Vector3 type though

Answer (score 0):

You can set `HorizontalAlignment` something like these inside the stackpanel...

```
<StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center">2. Draw a pattern</TextBlock>
                <Button x:Name="DeleteSiteButton" Content="Delete Site" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="DeleteSiteButton_Click"/>
                <Button x:Name="AddSiteButton" Content="Add Site" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="AddSiteButton_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I want to write it in C# syntax.

Comment: Those are properties on the actual C# object.  ButtonName.HorizontalAlignment....

Answer (score 0):

`StackPanel` control arranges child elements into a single line that can be oriented horizontally or vertically. When the `Orientation` property is set to `Vertical`(The default value is `Vertical`), the `VerticalAlignment` property of the button control will be invalid. Similarly, when the `Orientation` property is set to `Horizontal`, the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the button control will be invalid.

If you add a button control into a `StackPanel`, the  `HorizontalAlignment` property and `VerticalAlignment` property of the button control will not work at the same time, that is, the button control can not be centered in a `StackPanel`.

We suggest that you could add the button control to a `Grid` panel, like this:

```
Grid gridPanel1 = new Grid();

Button TestButton = new Button();
TestButton.Content = "Test";
TestButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
TestButton.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

gridPanel1.Children.Add(TestButton);

Window.Current.Content = gridPanel1;
```